# How to split to string Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have problem with split String Java this my string

```
 String valume="<z1> 0176543210010005160D2001000</z1 <z2>S4P6W7M522SC3OXX55K3NN77666N34M2</z2><z3>Moja Karta</z3><z4>90</z4>";
```

How to split this string have have two strings?

```
string1 = 0176543210010005160D2001000

string2 = S4P6W7M522SC3OXX55K3NN77666N34M2
string3=Moja Karta
string4=90
```

Comment: Would you mind to review your post to improve punctation and spelling?

Comment: You problem is near line 42 of your code.  If you show us what you have written, we will be able to provide a more accurate idea of where the problem is.

Comment: @rossum how you get to line 42.

Comment: @jack  I asked [Deep Thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_characters#Deep_Thought) the computer.

Comment: @rossum hahahha

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should work. But i don't really understood why you would do something like that

```
String wait =("<z1>0176543210010005160D2001000</z1>
               <z2>S4P6W7M522SC3OXX55K3NN77666N34M2</z2>");

String string1 = wait.split("</z1><z2>")[0].replace("<z1>","");
String string2 = wait.split("</z1><z2>")[1].replace("</z2>","");
System.out.println(string1);
System.out.println(string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to split your string if it follows a pattern as you mentioned in your example.

```
 String value="<z1>0176543210010005160D2001000</z1>
               <z2>S4P6W7M522SC3OXX55K3NN77666N34M2</z2>";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<z[0-9]>(.+?)</z[0-9]>");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
 while(m.find())
 {
      String result = m.group(1);
      System.out.println(result);
 }
```

Comment: how ascribe from while individual data?

Comment: @Marek I don't think I follow your question. If you are asking how to get each individual data from the matcher, you can loop thru the matcher like shown in line 7.